# Why does my app not load in the pinned icon? It makes a new one

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, visual-studio-2010

I usually pin visual studio to the task bar and then when I fire it up I get all instances appear as a stack of cards on the pin. However I have this interesting problem now where when I start it it creates a new temporary pin and all instances of the app load up on that pin. Annoying how do I stop this happening..[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used a taskbar tweaker tool like 7 Taskbar tweaker?
These tools allow you to change the default behavior.  The problem you desribe is one of those options.

Try using [7 Taskbar tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) and change this option:

- Grouping menu
- Disable: When not grouping, place new items next to the existing ones